# Bigquery - Analysis costs growing very fast - Data Studio Report

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am using the BigQuery to create reports into Data Studio Report from google cloud.
The "BigProblem" :) is:

After that, the costs of Analysis start to grow very fast, as you can see in this image:

[image]

I am using views to create these reports,  Views Like that:

```
SELECT
      footwear.style as style,
      SUM(footwear.MSRP_USD) as revenue,
      SUM(CAST(order_line.quantity AS NUMERIC)) as units_sold,
      SUM((SELECT SUM(order_line_refund.quantity) FROM myproject.shopify.ORDER_LINE_REFUND AS order_line_refund WHERE order_line_refund.order_line_id = order_line.id)) AS return_quantity,
FROM myproject.shopify.ORDER as orders
INNER JOIN myproject.shopify.ORDER_LINE as order_line on orders.id = order_line.order_id
INNER JOIN myproject.catalogDB.footwear_catalog as footwear on order_line.sku = footwear.sku
LEFT JOIN myproject.shopify.ORDER_LINE_REFUND as order_line_refund on order_line.id = order_line_refund.order_line_id
LEFT JOIN myproject.shopify.DISCOUNT_APPLICATION as discount_app on orders.id = discount_app.order_id
WHERE footwear.style IN ('Serena','Caro','Sloane') AND (discount_app.value < 100 OR discount_app.value IS NULL) AND orders.cancelled_at IS NULL
GROUP BY style
```

This simple query cost: 
Query complete (5.3 sec elapsed, 6.9 MB processed)

And I have others views much bigger than that.

I don't know if it is possible to turn off automatic data refresh in Data Studio. and I am quite sure to use views is not a Good Idea.

I can also consider using an extracted data source?
So I can schedule when the data is refreshed, it is a better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to save costs:

1. Materialise the report queries using a [batch job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries) into a separate table and run reports off that.
2. Ensure that the tables are [partitioned](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) and then use the partition key in  all your queries to filter the unnecessary data out.
3. You can use [BI engine](https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/getting-started-data-studio)  as the dynamic caching engine for your queries. This allow you to avoid reading from BigQuery.

PS: Check [Controlling BigQuery Costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/controlling-costs) as well.

Comment: Tks... I choose the first option and I am using this documentation to https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9019969